# Format JavaScript (jQuery weekcalendar) date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, date-format

I need to format a JavaScript date. I am using the jQuery Weekcalendar plugin and it kind of provides its own date format.

Input is:

```
Thu Jan 10 2013 11:15:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Output should be:

```
2013-10-01 11:15:00
```

Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) helps a lot when dealing with time and date in JavaScript

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'); // for example: 2013-10-01 11:15:00
```

Update:

To use moment.js with your existing date object you need to create a wrapper

```
var myDateWrapper = moment(calEvent.start);
console.log(myDateWrapper.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')) // that's what you want
```

Comment: Thank you. I already heard of moment.js, but how do I provide my date (calEvent.start) as input to moment.js?

Answer (score 0):

Look here. You can format output using plugin.

https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/Date-formating

Look also here:

https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/Script-options

You need to use this options:

> timeFormat: [string | default: “h:i a” ] – A format to use for times displayed by the calendar.
>   dateFormat: [string | default: “M d, Y” ] – A format to use for dates displayed in the calendar.

EDIT

```
$('#calendar').weekCalendar({
  dateFormat: 'y.m.d',
  timeFormat:"h:i:s"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Any chance to provide a piece of code? The date is stored in `calEvent.start`. How do I format it from there? Thank you!

Comment: The problem of this approach is: It changes the format globally in the calendar what I don't want. Further more, it doesn't work when new events are created. The format is still the same as posted in the question.